# Unable to access named servers, but I can if I use the IP address

Tags: windows, dns

In work I am unable to access (ping, run or browser) servers or URLs that are on server's outside my domain if I use the server name. I can connect if I use the IP address though.

My colleagues who are on the same domain as me are able to connect.

Not reachable: http://servername.domain.local/Service/Service.svc

Reachable: http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Service/Service.svc

Does anyone have any ideas why or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have no working DNS server in your LAN (or for your machine if it's only with your machine).

**If you have a network admin at your work, the best you can do is to talk with him but if you have not, you can try to fix it this way:**

If you have an internal DNS server, you need to configure it to use forwarders and if you have no DNS server, you need to configure your router to use your ISP's DNS server or use a public DNS like Google DNS (8.8.8.8) and to pass the DNS server address to the LAN.

If you have problem only with your machine, you can configure its network connection to use a public DNS server (the same Google DNS above will work too).

Answer (score 0):

Check with nslookup what IP address you receive.
If it's the address is incorrect, try "IPConfig /FlushDNS"

Comment: The IP address was incorrect but when I ran IPConfig /FlushDNS it said the DNS was flushed but nslookup still returned the same incorrect IP. nslookup is also reporting "Server: UnKnown"

Comment: So your machine has no DNS server (or a not working one) in its network config.